How to deal with multiple slack channels with one slack bolt app instance
I need to create an application (bot) using the Bolt framework provided by Slack. Users will be able to add it as an app to channels. The problem I foresee is that different commands will be sent to it at the same time on multiple channels. When processing the commands I have a lot of asynchronous operations. The question is will users not block each other? If one user sends a command and then another user sends a command before the previous one finishes then won't there be some blocking?
How to deal with this problem. I write the applications in JavaScript.
